# bootstrap 4 convert ul list to a column for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. I have a list of links that looks like this.
[image]

here is my html

```
            <ul class="list-inline footer-main-links">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/shop/">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/review/">Reviews</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
            ...
```

How can I make the list look like image below for smartphones? I would like to fully utilize bootstrap 4 classes/utilities.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `nav` with the responsive grid columns...

```
     <ul class="nav footer-main-links row text-center text-uppercase">
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/shop/">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/review/">Reviews</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/review/">Returns</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/review/">Story</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/review/">Partner</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item col-6 col-md"><a href="/review/">Refer a friend</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/LFROz8QVsi